# Extract element value in react

Tags: reactjs

calling function onclick event

```
<th onClick={this.sort}>Grades</th>
```

and in Function, trying to get the value of text.

```
  sort(e){
    console.log(e.target);

  }
```

**e.target** catch **`<th>Grades</th>`**

how can just get text ie **Grades'** without **th**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the text inside the element via `innerText`:

```
sort (e) {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
}
```

However, in this case it may be better to pass the text in directly, depending on your use case:

```
<th onClick={() => this.sort('Grades')}>Grades</th>
```

Comment: yes, I was trying this **onClick={this.sort('point')}** but not activity :)